# How to kill a process at specific time and restart it after x minutes?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I know how to kill a process using Powershell but I want to know that how can I kill a process at specified time and restart it after some minutes?

Eg. I want to kill notepad at 12.30pm and restart it after 5 minutes.

Comment: whether time to kill i.e 12.30 is hard codded? Means after restarting a process after 5 Min. you want to kill it again at specific time or what

Comment: @Amogh No its not hard coded..its a variable and user will enter the required time...once the process is killed and restarted, I dont want to kill the process again

Comment: This can get complicated pretty fast. Do you want it to survive reboots?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers No. Only when current  windows session is On.

Comment: Insert  `Start-Sleep -Seconds (5*60)` for a five min delay

Comment: Use Task Scheduler to start a script at 12:30 and have that script kill the process, sleep 5 minutes, then start the process again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/2d8hy4/pause_script_until_specific_time/

This works like charm. It has custom time variable, at end you can kill and restart a process using start-sleep variable...